# How to use Keycloak for user self-registration

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I want to use Keycloak as an authentication system to register, log in, and overall maintain the users of my app which consists of React.js in the frontend and Spring Boot in the backend. The users shall be able to register themselves without the interference of an admin and therefore also without requiring an initial access token as anyone shall be able to register on demand. As far as I can see there is no solution provided by Keycloak to directly register a user without having an access token or using the admin endpoints e.g. with this URL: *http://localhost:8089/auth/realms/mrtapp/protocol/openid-connect/registrations*. An idea that I have is to send the user registration credentials to the backend and use the admin URL in the backend to register the user but I am unsure if this is safe. Also, I managed to get to the registration page with Postman but I am having trouble coming up with the payload structure of the POST request for the registration of a user, so I would appreciate any incentive on how to come up with that.

EDIT: The URL which gets me to the login page is: http://localhost:8089/auth/realms/mrtapp/account/#/login 
and the URL which gets me to the registration page is:
http://localhost:8089/auth/realms/mrtapp/account/#/register 
At this point, I am stuck as I can't come up with the URL to send the payload (firstname,lastname,username,...) and also do not know what the payload looks like exactly. Does at this point Keycloak handle the User registration and there is no way to interfere and that's why I can't solve it with Postman?

I would appreciate any clarification if I am confusing something or if it is the right path to go. Even just giving me a heads-up if it is possible or not would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the current code so we can get a better understanding

Comment: @jmvcollaborator, there is no code yet. I have the keycloak set up and I am trying to send requests from Postman to keycloak. I can log in, but not register as I could not find out how the payload would look like for the POST request. Also, I am at the stage of building a concept but it confuses me if the registration of a user should be sent directly to Keycloak over the URL I specified (or if that is even possible) or if I need to send it to the backend first and then use the Admin Rest-api to register the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, now I put a JavaScript App using Keycloak.js in the frontend and this works fine, login and registering, but Postman still can't access the registration which I guess is because I am not including all required headers and payloads. I guess I will just continue using JS instead of Postman.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new realm in Keycloak or use an existing one.
2. Create a new client or use an existing one for which you want to enable self-registration.
3. In the client settings, under the "Login" tab, set the "User registration" option to "Enabled."
4. Under the "Registration" tab, you can customize the registration form and add custom fields.
5. Save the settings and test the registration flow by accessing the registration URL for the client. The registration URL can be found in the client settings under the "Installation" tab.
6. Use the Keycloak REST API to create a new user by making a POST request to the **registrations** endpoint. Here is an example request body:

```
{
  "username": "john.doe",
  "email": "john.doe@example.com",
  "enabled": true,
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "credentials": [{
    "type": "password",
    "value": "password"
  }]
}
```

7. After creating the user, Keycloak will send a verification email to the user's email address. The user needs to click on the verification link in the email to activate their account.

Comment: 3. Do you mean "Realm settings" as there is no login tab for the client? If so, done.
4. There is unfortunately no Registration tab but that is not important right now as I don't want to customize it anyway.
5.  The installation tab looks as follows: {
  "realm": "mrtapp",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8089/auth/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "mrtwebapp",
  "public-client": true,
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
} 
and using the auth-server-url directs me to the homepage with the docs etc.